# No puedo acceder al editor de Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente con la página web [www.ladrilleramelendez.com.co](http://www.ladrilleramelendez.com.co) y es que no puedo acceder al editor de wordpress, he intentado todas las rutas posibles para acceder al editor (/wp-admin, /login.php etc.) pero al parecer hay un error de direccionamiento pues siempre me dirige al home del sitio y no tengo forma de editar la página, alguien se le ocurre alguna posible solución?
Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto no es un problema de programacion, parece un problema de tu configuracion, verifica cual es la ruta de tu administrador, y si no te hackearon y cambiaron la misma.

Comment: Entra por FTP y busca algún plugin para cambiar el back. Si no es nada de eso, prueba a reemplazar el contenido de `wp-admin` por el original de WP o incluso por Shell puedes reinstalar el **core** de WP. Si buscas los comandos Shell de WP veras que varios te pueden ayudar.

Comment: si tenes acceso x terminal [`refresca wordpress core, plugins y themes`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/202028/81450)